# Function Evaluation in Table

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, list-manipulation

Apologies in advance: this is a really basic question, and I am sure it has been answered, but I don't know enough mathematica to even find the answer.

I have a differential equation I want to solve. Specifically I want to know the solution at some long time T (say T=50). The differential equation involves some parameters, and I want to define a function to be the solution of the differential equation as a function of these parameters.

What I did was

```
Solu[w1_, w2_, w3_, alph_, T_] := 
 Flatten[Evaluate[{u[T], v[T], w[T], x[T], y[T], z[T]} /.  
    NDSolve[{u'[t] == 
       w1 + x[t] Sin[v[t] - u[t]] + y[t] Sin[w[t] - u[t]], 
      v'[t] == w2 + x[t] Sin[u[t] - v[t]] + z[t] Sin[w[t] - v[t]], 
      w'[t] == w3 + y[t] Sin[u[t] - w[t]] + z[t] Sin[v[t] - w[t]], 
      x'[t] == -alph x[t] + Cos[u[t] - v[t]], 
      y'[t] == -alph y[t] + Cos[u[t] - w[t]], 
      z'[t] == -alph z[t] + Cos[v[t] - w[t]], u[0] == 0, v[0] == 0, 
      w[0] == .0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}, {u, v, w, x, y, 
      z}, {t, 0, T}]]]
```

Which is fine if I want to find the value at a specified point:

```
In[202]:= Solu[-1.0, -1, 2, .3, 20] 

Out[202] = {-0.107791, -0.107791, 0.215582, 3.32755, 3.14742, 3.14742}
```

But Mathematica gags if I try to make a table of values, or graph the solutions.

```
In[203]:= Table[Solu[-x,-1,1+x,.3,50],{x,0,2}]
```

> NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation. >>

I understand that this is related to the way mathematica first builds the table and then evaluates, but I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Functions which use numeric techniques should have their arguments restricted to numeric values.

`Solu[w1_?NumericQ, w2_?NumericQ, w3_?NumericQ, alph_?NumericQ, 
  T_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `x` as both a dependent variable in `NDSolve` and an index in `Table`.  Instead, try,

```
Table[Solu[-a, -1, 1 + a, .3, 50], {a, 0, 2}]
(* {{7.19845*10^-22, -0.102113, 0.102113, 3.31597, 3.31597, 3.26406}, 
    {-0.10725, -0.10725, 0.214501, 3.33333, 3.16227, 3.16227}, 
    {-67.8836, -67.7287, 135.612, 3.29475, 0.133514, 0.162306}} *)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was dumb of me.